# why redirect URL field is disable in strapi under providers section

Tags: strapi

why the Redirect URL is disabled, but as per documentation we can edit it.. https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/plugins/users-permissions.html#strapi-configuration

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s_vQqQ4tpHs), it's suppose to fill up automatically. Although there is still a bug with strapi v3.0.2